# Can I use the second band in my dual-band router as an AP with the first band being in "client mode"? (dd-WRT)

Tags: wireless-networking, router, dd-wrt, wireless-bridge, bridge-router

I couldn't register to dd-WRT forum because the registration code is case sensitive and I don't have the same case "looks" in my country as they had in their website... So, the second place of choice was here :).

Situation: I'm getting my WAN from another router by using one wireless "band", which is in "client mode". I have a dual-band router.

What I want: I want my second band to work in AP and resend the connection being obtained by that same WAN. (Using same DHCP server as well). When I put it in AP, it transmits the signal but I the DHCP doesn't work for it.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I'm trying to do something very similar and I'm interested in the response. I *think* if you want to carry forward using the primary router's DHCP you'd use Repeater mode not Client. My understanding is that simply "repeats" the network rather than subscribing to it.

Answer (score 1):

Does [this](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Universal_Wireless_Repeater) sound like what you're trying to do?